# Repeatition of map div in ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have a card where it is repeated multiple times in a page, In the card I have a google map which shows the location of a particular point. 
I am getting the google side response as

```
Error

at new nc (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCEHWgPqgJiWcySMQPZZ7W7Cjpugl928Fw&callback=renderMap:47:499)
at Object._.oc (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCEHWgPqgJiWcySMQPZZ7W7Cjpugl928Fw&callback=renderMap:48:96)
at ah (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCEHWgPqgJiWcySMQPZZ7W7Cjpugl928Fw&callback=renderMap:98:420)
at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCEHWgPqgJiWcySMQPZZ7W7Cjpugl928Fw&callback=renderMap:137:53
at Object.google.maps.Load (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCEHWgPqgJiWcySMQPZZ7W7Cjpugl928Fw&callback=renderMap:21:5)
at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCEHWgPqgJiWcySMQPZZ7W7Cjpugl928Fw&callback=renderMap:136:20
at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCEHWgPqgJiWcySMQPZZ7W7Cjpugl928Fw&callback=renderMap:137:68
```

Html code is as follows

```
<div class="body" ng-repeat="hospital in hospitals">
  <div class="list card">
    <div>
      <div id="map{{$index}}" style="height:200px;width:100%;" class="renderMap(hospital)"></div>
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=renderMap">

      </script>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In controller, it is as follows

```
$scope.renderMap = renderMap;
function renderMap(hospital){
   $scope.details_for_map = hospital;
   console.log($scope.details_for_map);
   initMap();
}

  function initMap() {

          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $scope.details_for_map.geometry.location.lat, $scope.details_for_map.geometry.location.lng);
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'+$scope.details_for_map.index), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: latlng
          });
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
          });
        }
```

As I am new to ionic and angular js I am not able to figure out what I am doing incorrectly. Please let me know what I can do about it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/bwdoA

Comment: look at this example this will help you

Comment: Dixit I am not using ng-map. I am calling google maps from java script.